# Client Server File Transfer, FIN ACK received right after the connection is established

Tags: c#, web-services, sockets, azure, tcp

I am having a hard time figuring this out, so any help would be much appreciated. 
I'm trying to implement a client/server file transfer software suite between a web server (MS Azure) and some embedded systems running on Windows Embedded Standard. On the web server side I have the Client application(Web APP + ASMX WebService), and on each embedded system I have a server application (Winforms app) listening on port 8020, as illustrated on the following figure.

[system architecture diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrBj4.png)

My local testing environment consists of my dev pc (Windows 10, VS2015, 192.168.1.2, hosting both Web APP and the WebService) and two robots all connected to our local LAN (Robot Client 1 : 192.168.1.80, Robot Client 2 : 192.168.1.132)

Locally, everything works perfectly. the file transfer is completed successfully. This is, however, not the case, once I deploy both web app and webservice to our MS Azure Web server. I used wireshark to monitor the traffic and see exactly what was going on. As you can see from the attached figure. the client application installed on the server sends [FIN, ACK] right after the connection is established?!

[Wireshark capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MCaW.png)

I have added the corresponding endpoint on the Virtual Machine.I also have the port 8020 open on my router locally and I have created an inbound rule on the same port on each firewall on both robots.

As to the code,
WebApplication :

```
private void TrasnferMAJ(string RobotsRef, string SelectedTime, string robotName, string Vmaj)
    {
        WebserviceRobots ws = new WebserviceRobots();
        ws.SendMAJCompleted += new SendMAJCompletedEventHandler(SendMAJCompleted);
        ws.SendMAJAsync(RobotsRef, "", robotName, Vmaj);   
        ws.SendMAJ(RobotsRef, "", robotName, Vmaj);

    }

     private void SendMAJCompleted(object sender, SendMAJCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        string UpdateStatus = "";
        if (e != null)
            UpdateStatus = e.Result;
    }
```

Web Service :

```
 [WebMethod]
    public string SendMAJ(string RobotsRef, string SelectedTime, string robotName, string Vmaj)
    {
        int port = 8020;
        string message = "Envoi terminé avec succès"; // Transfer completed successfully 
        byte[] SendingBuffer = null;
        TcpClient client = null;
        NetworkStream netstream = null;
        try
        {

           client = new TcpClient(robotName, port); // initiate comm
           netstream = client.GetStream(); // Network stream to be used
            FileStream Fs = new FileStream(GetMajPath(Vmaj), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            int NoOfPackets = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(Fs.Length) / Convert.ToDouble(BufferSize))); // the number of packets to be sent 

            int TotalLength = (int)Fs.Length, CurrentPacketLength = 0; // initializing TotalLength to stream length (nbr of bytes)
            for (int i = 0; i < NoOfPackets; i++)
            {
                if (TotalLength > BufferSize) // if we still have more than one Kbytes
                {
                    CurrentPacketLength = BufferSize;
                    TotalLength = TotalLength - CurrentPacketLength; // totalLength : the amount of data that has not been sent yet
                }
                else
                CurrentPacketLength = TotalLength; // this here could be less than a byte. 
                SendingBuffer = new byte[CurrentPacketLength]; 
                Fs.Read(SendingBuffer, 0, CurrentPacketLength); // reading the data from the filestream, & writing it to the SendingBuffer
                netstream.Write(SendingBuffer, 0, (int)SendingBuffer.Length); // Writing the SendingBuffer Buffer to the network stream
            }
            Fs.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            message = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            netstream.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
        // if it all goes well, the message should be ="Envoi terminé avec succès",else it would be assigned the exception message.
        return message;
    }
```

The Server application (WinForms) :

```
public partial class ReceiveMAJs : Form
{
    private const int BufferSize = 1024;
    public string Status = string.Empty;
    public Thread T = null;
    public ReceiveMAJs()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ReceiveMAJs_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "Serveur en cours d'exécution...";
        // Creating a seperate thread for recieving the MAJ file
        ThreadStart Ts = new ThreadStart(StartReceiving);
        T = new Thread(Ts);
        T.Start();

    }

    public void StartReceiving()
    {
        ReceiveTCP(8020);
    }
    public void ReceiveTCP(int portN)
    {
        TcpListener Listener = null;
        try
        {
            Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, portN);
            Listener.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        byte[] RecData = new byte[BufferSize];
        int RecBytes;

        for (;;)
        {
            TcpClient client = null;
            NetworkStream netstream = null;
            Status = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                string message = "Mettre à jour ";
                string caption = "Connexion entrante";
                MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
                DialogResult result;


                if (Listener.Pending()) // true if there are any pending connections
                {
                    client = Listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                    netstream = client.GetStream();
                    Status = "Connecter au serveur des MAJs\n";
                    result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons);

                    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {

                         string SaveFileName = string.Empty;
                         SaveFileDialog DialogSave = new SaveFileDialog();
                         DialogSave.Filter = "Tous les fichiers (*.*)|*.*";
                         DialogSave.RestoreDirectory = true; 
                         DialogSave.Title = "L'emplacement de sauvegarde?";
                         DialogSave.InitialDirectory = @"C:/";

                        Invoke((Action)(() => {
                            if (DialogSave.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                                SaveFileName = DialogSave.FileName;
                        }));

                        if (SaveFileName != string.Empty)
                        {
                        int totalrecbytes = 0;
                        FileStream Fs = new FileStream(SaveFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                        while ((RecBytes = netstream.Read(RecData, 0, RecData.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            Fs.Write(RecData, 0, RecBytes);
                            totalrecbytes += RecBytes;
                        }
                        Fs.Close();
                        }
                        netstream.Close();
                        client.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(5); // avoiding overworking the processor
        }
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        T.Abort();
        this.Close();
    }


}
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Does you application have access rights to read/write at server?

Comment: @jdweng Could you please elaborate your question? are you referring to the Server application (WinForms) on the Client? or the Client application (WebAPP) on the WebServer? If it's the latter, I have set R/W permissions for IIS_IUSRS on the directory where I have my files stored. but i don't really see how can that cause an issue? the transfer is done from the web app to the winforms app.Thanks for your answer

Comment: The issue doesn't seem to be at the socket level.  The issue is with the application level read/write access. The WebApp is executed as a Guest Account with no read/write access on the PC. It looks like the connection completes but then no data is transferred.

Comment: @jdweng Exactly! the connection is established but just right after the client app on the web server sends a [FIN, ACK] to the server application installed on the robot.

Comment: @jdweng  On the webserver, both my WebAPP and WebService are running under Application pool identity. on my wwwroot directoty, I have a folder called "sites" containing four other folders : AxWebAPP (published WebApp), WebService(Published WebService), ControllerUpdates (folder containing updates, zip file format, these are the files that need to be sent to the server application "WinFomrs" on the client i.e. the robot), and ControllerUpdateXMLFiles (containing some dynamically created xml files)

Comment: @jdweng these xml files are created by the webservice). on both ControllerUpdates and ControllerUpdateXMLFiles, I have set R/W permissions for Users and IIS_Users, I don't have a problem with writing to the server, as the xml files are created successfully each time. do you have any other suggestions as to what could cause this behaviour? 
Thank you again for your answer,

Comment: So the xml files are being transferred but other types are not.  So either files are being blocked or the format of the files have issues.  Don't know if this is due to being a French Server.  Are you using FTP.  If so you may need to set transfer mode from text to binary.  I would try transferring as 64 bit string

Comment: You are closing the connection after one message is being received.  Why.  A lot of examples on msdn close connections after each message and then reconnect.  I personally prefer to leave connections open until all messages are received and sent.  If you close then you have to reconnect.  Also with TCP you can get a keep Alive message which is a datagram with contents being zero bytes.  So as soon as your server gets a message with zero bytes it closes connection.  Wire shark show length as zero.

Comment: Hello @jdweng, I hope you are doing well, I just want to give you an update on my progress on this topic. It wasn't an issue at the socket level as you pointed out. I found the problem with a webservice method that searches through the directory containing the updates (the zip files) using DirectoryInfo.getfiles(). i guess the right permissions are not correctly setup. Anyway, to avoid the whole shebang of setting up the right permissions. i added a simple element to an xml file that contains infos on each update file, this element represents a path to the exact zip file

Comment: @jdweng  and wrote a simple webmethod to retrieve the right file. Thank you for your replies. How can i upvote your comment? i don't seem to be able to?